# ColumnTransformer and Pipelines: how to properly use it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to build a pipeline but everytime I get rid off some issue, I end with a new one. `ColumnTransformer` is really playing with me. I want to make some transformations in some columns of a dataframe with the following code:

```
def sum_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["relatives"]  # feature names out

def sum_relatives(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    X_copy['total_relatives'] = X_copy['SibSp'] + X_copy['Parch']
    return X_copy

def cat_travel_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["travel_cat"]  # feature names out

def categorize_travel(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()

#X_copy['total_relatives'] = X_copy['SibSp'] + X_copy['Parch']

conditions = [
    (X_copy['total_relatives'] == 0),
    (X_copy['total_relatives'] >= 1) & (X_copy['total_relatives'] <= 3),
    (X_copy['total_relatives'] >= 4)
]
categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']

X_copy['traveling_category'] = np.select(conditions, categories, default='Unknown')
return X_copy

class_order = [[1, 2, 3]]

ord_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    OrdinalEncoder(categories=class_order)    
    )

def interval_name(function_transformer, feature_names_in):
    return ["interval"]  # feature names out

def age_transformer(X):
    X_copy = X.copy()
    median_age_by_class = X_copy.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].median().reset_index()
    median_age_by_class.columns = ['Pclass', 'median_age']
    for index, row in median_age_by_class.iterrows():
       class_value = row['Pclass']
    median_age = row['median_age']
        X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'] = X_copy.loc[X_copy['Pclass'] == class_value, 'Age'].fillna(median_age)
    bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    X_copy['age_interval'] = pd.cut(X_copy['Age'], bins=bins)
    X_copy.drop(["Age", "Pclass"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    return X_copy

def age_processor():
    return make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(age_transformer, feature_names_out=interval_name),
        OneHotEncoder()
        )

total_relatives_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(sum_relatives, feature_names_out=sum_name)
)

travel_category_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    FunctionTransformer(categorize_travel, feature_names_out=cat_travel_name)
)

cat_pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore")
    )

num_pipeline = make_pipeline(
        StandardScaler()
    )

custom_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("total_relatives", total_relatives_pipeline),
    ("travel_category", travel_category_pipeline),
    #("cat_encoder", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))
])

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
        ("ord", ord_pipeline, ['Pclass']),
        ("age_processing", age_processor(), ['Pclass', 'Age']),
        #("custom", custom_pipeline, ['SibSp', 'Parch']),
        ("cat", cat_pipeline, ['Sex', 'Embarked']),
        ("num", num_pipeline, ['Fare']),
    ])
```

Questions:

- why do I need to drop the `Age` and `Pclass` columns inside the `age_transformer` function? When I do not drop it, the `Age` column is returned in the dataframe, but I do not want that: I want it to be transformed and dropped, like every other transformed column inside the `ColumnTransformer`.
- How can I tell the `OneHotEncoder` that I want it to transform only the categorical columns and not the int? When I call it in the `age_processor` it is giving me more columns than expected.

Finaly, running the above code (with the # to not run some lines) it is raising an error:

```
data_processed = preprocessing.fit_transform(titanic_data)
data_processed.shape

 Out: (891, 15)
```

but
preprocessing.get_feature_names_out()

raises:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[282], line 1
----> 1 preprocessing.get_feature_names_out()
[...]
ValueError: input_features is not equal to feature_names_in_
```

But, if I take the `OneHotEncoder()` out in the `age_processor()` function it raises no error:

```
data_processed.shape
```

outputs: `(891, 8)

and `preprocessing.get_feature_names_out()` outputs:

```
array(['ord__Pclass', 'age_processing__interval', 'cat__Sex_female',
   'cat__Sex_male', 'cat__Embarked_C', 'cat__Embarked_Q',
   'cat__Embarked_S', 'num__Fare'], dtype=object)
```

And I have no clue why.